# How to define cumulative normal distribution using symbolic math

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have the following code in MATLAB

```
x=sym('x',[1 2]);
DV=x(1)*ED+x(2);
sv=x(1)*DV;
DD=DV./sv;
p=normcdf(-DD);
```

where DV and ED are both 13242 x 1 vectors. Up to DD all it is ok. When i define p as above, i obtain this message:

> Error using symfun>validateArgNames (line 205)
>
> Second input must be a scalar or vector of unique symbolic variables.

When i define `p=1./(1+exp(-DD))` all it is ok. So there is a problem with `normcdf`.

Any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`normcdf`, like most of the functions in the Statistics toolbox, does not support symbolic input. The documentation does not make this clear and I agree that the error message is extremely useless (you might [contact MathWorks and file a service request about this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/service_requests/contact_support.do) to suggest that they add support for symbolic math to the Statistics toolbox).

The `normcdf` function doesn't do anything magical. You can use `p = 0.5*erfc(DD./sqrt(2))` in place of `p = normcdf(-DD)`. This will also be faster. Type `edit normcdf` in your command to see the code for the function. There's lots of error checking and cases specific to floating-point which is why the function errors with symbolic inputs.

Another option is to use MuPAD's [`stats::normalCDF`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/stats-normalcdf.html) from [within Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html) (this function might only be supported in recent releases). For example:

```
x = sym('x',[1 2]);
ED = ones(1,3);
DV = x(1)*ED+x(2);
sv = x(1)*DV;
DD = DV./sv;
DDstr = char(-DD);
p = evalin(symengine, ['f:=stats::normalCDF(0,1):map(' DDstr(9:end-2) ',x->f(x))'])
```

where `f` defines a [procedure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/proc.html) implementing a symbolic normal CDF with mean 0 and variance 1. MuPAD's [`map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/map.html) function is also used to vectorize this.  All in all, this option is probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From the MATLAB help of `normcdf`

> `x` can be a vector, matrix, or multidimensional array.

I.e., it cannot be a symbolic variable.

Try

```
syms y;
p=normcdf(y)
```

Doesn't work. Since `DD` is a symbolic variable, it will not work. Why would you want a vector of a few thousand symbolic values anyway? Wouldn't it be more efficient to run the script for a specific, non-symbolic value for `x`?

Comment: Hi sanchises thanks for your response. Well, actually the variable p will be entered in an objective function F and then optimize F w.r.t x. But since i cannot define p, F does't too.

Comment: I would look at wether there are smarter ways of getting what you want. Optimizing 13k symbolic functions doesn't seem effective to me... Try finding a relation between x and F; usually, an approximation (linearization) can do surprisingly well.

Comment: There's nothing about the phrase "x can be a vector, matrix, or multidimensional array" that precludes symbolic variables, which can be scalars, vectors, matrices, or multidimensional arrays themselves.

Comment: True, but in my experience, the MATLAB documentation will explicityly mention it when the input is allowed to be symbolic and just plainly not mention when it can't be symbolic.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to it. Instead of using the command normcdf, i must define the equation of the cumulative density function as it is, where X=-DD