# How to calculate the integral of log-normal distribution with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, distribution, symbolic-math, symbolic-integration

I want to calculate the part-expectation of log-normal distribution via:

```
m = 1;
v = 2;
mu = log((m^2)/sqrt(v+m^2));
sigma = sqrt(log(v/(m^2)+1));

syms x;
d = x*lognpdf(x,mu,sigma);

int(d, x, 0, 10);
```

However, MATLAB says:

> Error using symfun>validateArgNames (line 211) Second input must be a
>   scalar or vector of unique symbolic variables.
>
> Error in symfun (line 45)
>               y.vars = validateArgNames(inputs);
>
> Error in sym/subsasgn (line 771)
>                   C = symfun(B,[inds{:}]);
>
> Error in lognpdf (line 36) x(x <= 0) = Inf;
>
> Error in untitled (line 7) d = x*lognpdf(x,mu,sigma);

I even tried to just calculate the integral of the pdf by:

```
m = 1;
v = 2;
mu = log((m^2)/sqrt(v+m^2));
sigma = sqrt(log(v/(m^2)+1));

syms x;
d = lognpdf(x,mu,sigma);

int(d, x, 0, 10);
```

But there are still errors, and MATLAB says:

> Error using symfun>validateArgNames (line 211) Second input must be a
>   scalar or vector of unique symbolic variables.
>
> Error in symfun (line 45)
>               y.vars = validateArgNames(inputs);
>
> Error in sym/subsasgn (line 771)
>                   C = symfun(B,[inds{:}]);
>
> Error in lognpdf (line 36) x(x <= 0) = Inf;
>
> Error in untitled (line 7) d = lognpdf(x,mu,sigma);

I really don't know what happened. Should the integral of the pdf be the cdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [an answer several months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25936113/3121310), the Statistics Toolbox doesn't support the Symbolic Toolbox currently.
Therefore, you can proceed by hard coding the PDF itself and integrating it:

```
d = exp(-(log(x)-mu)^2/(2*sigma^2))/(x*sigma*sqrt(2*pi));
int(d, x, 0, 10);
```

Or you can use the [`logncdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/logncdf.html) function, which may be cleaner.

Comment: It works! Thank you! But cannot understand why they don't support this, since it seems easy.